# A word for "asking for directions only to find you're almost there"

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for "when you ask for directions and you find you're almost there"?

For example,

"After the battery on my GPS died out I drove around looking for the party only to pull over and ask someone where you lived. They pointed to the house just down the block I'd been circling around for what felt like forever."

"Wow, you really had a (...) moment."

Comment: Can you use more words (than the one you seek) to give a clearer idea of what you're meaning...

Comment: @Dan I am thinking of the stereotype that men don't like to ask for directions and the irony (?) of finally asking for directions when you are lost (and don't want to admit it) only to find out that the place you couldn't find is right in front of you.

Comment: So... the person who didn't ask directions has some kind of epiphany - realisation that it would have been better had they asked for help...?

Comment: @Dan sure - the epiphany could also be realizing how much time they could have saved by asking - possibly a little embarrassed by their stubbornness, but also their joy at finally getting where they wanted to go.

Comment: That's a lot of meanings to ask of a single word...!

Comment: @Dan oh fersher, I figure usage will convey the subtlety, but that's why I stuck to the basic "when you ask for directions and you find you're almost there". Maybe a portmanteau or something in German...

Comment: On the lighter side, you had a "men are from Mars" moment.

Comment: I can't think of a single word, but you had a "can't-see-the-forest-for-the-trees" moment, or, shorter, a "forest-for-the-trees" moment..  A "hidden-in-plain-sight" moment.  Shorter still, a "Purloined Letter" moment, after an Edgar Allen Poe detective story in which the vital clue is hidden in plain sight.

Comment: Perhaps you had a spot-off moment.

Answer (score 1):

That could be *fortuitous* in this case.

Answer (score 0):

In a broader sense, you had what might be called a **blonde** moment.

> ### have a blonde moment
>
> <sup>INFORMAL</sup> to forget something or do something silly, in a way that is sometimes thought to be typical of women with blonde hair

-- [Cambridge English Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/have-a-blonde-moment)

I can't think of a more specific word, but the whole scenario reminds me of when someone is searching everywhere for their glasses only to find, upon asking someone, that they are on top of their head. Perhaps a *glasses-on-top-of-your-head* moment?